# Semantic Issue with Facebook FBSDK Corekit

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk

I have several issues with the Facebook FBSDK Kit, which my fellow programmers in the project don't have. I have already set up the pods, cleaned the build files, deleted the pods, updated them but I get the same errors again.

Semantic issue - Unknown type name 'SFAuthenticationSession'
AR semantic issue -  No known instance method for selector 'initWithURL:callbackURLScheme:completionHandler:'

in the FBSDKApplicationDelegate.m

I am using the FBSDK Corekit 4.25.0.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

[In my developer team I am the only one who gets this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWDnw.png)

[Second error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SAPi.png)

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using ? What version are your coworkers using ?

Comment: @deadbeef We are all using XCode 9.0 beta. The fault's cause is probably due to the FBSDK Vesion 4.25.0. The coworkers are using 4.24.0. However I was not able to downgrade to 4.24 

»None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `FacebookCore (~> 4.24.0)`.«

Comment: Make sure you're all using the latest beta then.

Comment: That does not change anything.

Answer (score 3):

The bug you are experiencing seems to be an issue the 4.25.0 SDK for Facebook.  I had the same problem (using Xcode Version 9.0 beta (9M136h)), and I was able to resolve the problem by going back to version 4.24.0.  In the Podfile, I was thrown dependency errors when I tried to do this:

```
pod "FacebookCore", "4.24.0"
pod "FacebookLogIn", "4.24.0"
```

I am not sure why the above isn't working.  However, I followed the instructions on [Facebook's iOS SDK Git Repository](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), and changed it to this:

```
pod "FBSDKLoginKit", "4.24.0"
pod "FBSDKCoreKit", "4.24.0"
pod "FBSDKShareKit", "4.24.0"
```

I ran "pod clean" and then "pod install", and my project worked again without any errors.  Hopefully this is helpful.

Also, make sure in your Xcode project, you import the Facebook SDK like this:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit
```

Comment: I found a solution with which it works with FBSDK 4.25.0!

Make sure to update on the latest Xcode 9.0 Beta 4.0.

If still not working, 
 
* sudo gem update cocoapods
 * rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
 * rm -rf schnapp_ios/Pods
 * rm schnapp_ios/Podfile.lock
 * pod --version (should be at least 1.3.0)
 * pod install

This is what worked for my team!

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened using Xcode 10.1 and updating FBSDKCoreKit pod from 4.31.1 to 4.40.0. I just revert to previous version

Answer (score 0):

Use following Corekit version of FBSDK, In this version has solved this issue.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.0'
```